# OpacityConverter hack

Tags: .net, converters

How do I implement an OpacityConverter that accepts values beyond 100% ? Like 120% or 150%.

Thanks.

Comment: what is supposed to happen with 120% or 150%?

Comment: Standard OpacityConverter raises an exception saying that valid values are only from 0 to 100%

Comment: Yes, I am aware of that. What do **you** want to happen? Default to 100%?

Comment: No, accept 120% or 150% as well.

Comment: What is the sense of that? There is no such thing as 120% opacity. You can't make something more visible than fully visible.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should adjust your code instead. Before providing your value to the converter, run it through `Math.Min/Max`:

```
    //adjusted = Max(0, Min(1.0, input))

decimal stuff1 = 1.1m;
decimal stuff2 = -0.1m;
decimal stuff3 = 0.5m;

decimal correct1 = Math.Max(0m, Math.Min(1.0m, stuff1)); // 1.0
decimal correct2 = Math.Max(0m, Math.Min(1.0m, stuff2)); // 0.0
decimal correct3 = Math.Max(0m, Math.Min(1.0m, stuff3)); // 0.5
```

Any opacity below 0% or above 100% doesn't make any sense, simply because you can't make anything *more* visible than *fully visible*; and likewise, you can't make something *less* visible than *not visible*.